# Vb.Net javascript serializer

Tags: json, vb.net, javascriptserializer

I have a JSON string that I have deserialized using JavascriptSerializer in VB.NET. I need to loop through the deserialized data but am facing a challenge with the nested objects. How can I access SubBookingId from the JSON String below using a for each loop in vb.net

```
{
  "Reservations": {
    "Reservation": [
      {
        "BookingTran": [
          {
            "SubBookingId": "459",
            "TransactionId": "1872700000000000699",
            "Createdatetime": "2022-03-08 09:58:51",
            "Modifydatetime": "2022-03-08 09:58:51",
            "Status": "New",
            "IsConfirmed": "1",
            "CurrentStatus": "Confirmed Reservation",
            "VoucherNo": ""
          }
        ]
        
      
      },
      {
        "BookingTran": [
          {
            "SubBookingId": "460",
            "TransactionId": "1872700000000000700",
            "Createdatetime": "2022-03-08 10:00:17",
            "Modifydatetime": "2022-03-08 10:00:17",
            "Status": "New",
            "IsConfirmed": "1",
            "CurrentStatus": "Confirmed Reservation",
            "VoucherNo": "",
            
            
          }
        ],
      
        "IsChannelBooking": "1"
      }
      
      
    ]
   
  }
}
```

I am using a soap web service that returns a JSON string. The deserialization code is as below:

```
 Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(JsonString)
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code and Model you used to deserialize this JSON.

Comment: Are you using Ajax? According to [System.Web.Script.Serialization Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization?view=netframework-4.8) _For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, use the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use Newtonsoft.Json. This type was intended to provide serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications._

Comment: I have updated my code to include how I did Deserialization.

Comment: Where are your classes?

Comment: Also, the JSON you presented here is not an array of objects, it's a single object where the first property is an array of objects. With `objects` I don't mean an `Object` Type, you should deserialize to .Net classes. [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) may come in handy.